# How to substitute a variable with real value in a xml file , which is in another dependency jar file by Maven

Tags: java, maven

We have a project called web-app1 and has a dependency on another jar file called core-app.jar which is provided by another team as a shared library , yet there is a hibernate.cfg.xml in this core-app.jar (inside of the jar), with content as below.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions"><![CDATA[false 'N', true 'Y']]></property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
       <!-- Search Configurations -->
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${lucene.index.home}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.merge_factor">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.max_buffered_docs">10</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As we see in the Search Configurations section, there is a variable ${lucene.index.home} that should be replaced by other projects on different OS platform,
so the question, does maven provide a way to filter a dependency jar file and filter the content? any plugins ? war:war  , unzip ? dependencies ?  I couldn't figure a fast way to do that.  it looks to me , no matter what plugin would be adopted, the plugin needs to do 4 things basically.

- 1  unpack the jar in
  process-resources phase.
- 2     substitute the ${var} with
  value    defined in profile.
- 3  pack it    again back into a jar.
- 4  need to copy it back from the
  packing/unpacking workspace back to
  the maven process path ??

did anyone run into this similar requirement before.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that those values are meant to be set at runtime, likely as VM arguments.  It doesn't make sense to provide a jar file that has to be modified to be able to be used.

Comment: in this case, ${lucene.index.home}  have to be replaced when we make a build web-app1.war if we need to deploy to different platform and the thing is on client side , os/jvm level configuration is untouchable by us,  we are able to ask for creating a folder on the production server , yet we can't pursue JVM changes since there are more security concerns and lots of other apps running up there from different companies. in order to implement this , we came up with the plan as above to substitute this value in the jar when we make the war file.

Comment: Then it would make more sense to have a properties file that you could provide the customized values in instead of changing the jar at build time.  If you have to do a new build for every environment, you are on your way to defeating Java  8-)

Comment: in a complex distributed system , lots of companies got involved and anticipated with different priorities with C-P style in a linear or lateral way. like core which is way highly abstracted for over a 2 dozens of sub/p-apps to composite or inherited. if it's a simple app or fully self-controlled app, it's easy to do property or jvm and etc. yet, to meet a complex development env. Java or Python whatever techs we are going to use has to compromise on higher design . we use technologies, and meantime if necessary we beat technologies for a reason

Answer (score 0):

If you really really REALLY have to do filtering at build time for configuration purposes, those configuration files should be filtered, NOT your dependencies.  Then, you should either bundle said file into multiple artifacts (assuming of course you are targeting multiple environments), or be provided outside the built artifact as an externalized resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question?